# How can I generate a list of Reddit saved items using jraw?

Tags: java, api, reddit

I'm trying to generate a list of all my saved reddit items using [JRAW](https://github.com/thatJavaNerd/JRAW).

I've gone through the [Quickstart](https://github.com/thatJavaNerd/JRAW/wiki/Quickstart) , and successfully managed to login and retrieve information, and I can get a list of items on the Frontpage from the [Cookbook](https://github.com/thatJavaNerd/JRAW/wiki/Cookbook), but I can't work out how I would get a list of my saved items (comments and posts) or a list of my own posts (also comments and posts).

The saved items are at `https://www.reddit.com/user/<username>/saved/`, but I don't know how to get jraw to retrieve and parse that, or if the api uses a different URL.

Edit: I think I probably need to use a [UserContributionPaginator](https://thatjavanerd.github.io/JRAW/docs/latest/net/dean/jraw/paginators/UserContributionPaginator.html), but I haven't quite worked out exactly how to get it to work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out.

```
package com.jraw;

import net.dean.jraw.RedditClient;
import net.dean.jraw.http.UserAgent;
import net.dean.jraw.http.oauth.Credentials;
import net.dean.jraw.http.oauth.OAuthData;
import net.dean.jraw.http.oauth.OAuthException;
import net.dean.jraw.models.Contribution;
import net.dean.jraw.models.Listing;
import net.dean.jraw.paginators.UserContributionPaginator;

public class printSaved {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        UserAgent myUserAgent = UserAgent.of("desktop", "com.jraw.printSaved", "v0.01", "user");
        RedditClient redditClient = new RedditClient(myUserAgent);
        String username = "username";
        Credentials credentials = Credentials.script(username, "<password>", "<clientId>", "<clientSecret>");

        OAuthData authData = null;
        try {
            authData = redditClient.getOAuthHelper().easyAuth(credentials);
        } catch (OAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        redditClient.authenticate(authData);

        UserContributionPaginator saved = new UserContributionPaginator(redditClient,"saved",username);

        Listing<Contribution> savedList = saved.next();

        for (Contribution item : savedList) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```